# How do you correctly seed a prisma DB with a custom file that has multiple mutations?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, mutation, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am trying to seed my Prisma DB using a custom file I created which I then reference in `prisma.yml`. In this file, I have a few mutations - nothing too crazy. Everything seems to be working fine when I have ONE mutation. However, if I add more than one I end up getting this error: `Must provide operation name if query contains multiple operations: {"response":{"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"Must provide operation name if query contains multiple operations"}],"status":200}`. I assumed this `operation name` is the `createSomething` in `mutation createSomething {...}`, but I guess that is not the case. Is there anything I am missing here?

Having multiple mutations in the playground also seems to be working fine. Looks like the problem is when the seeder tries to run them all one after the other.

prisma.yml

```
seed:
  import: seeds/something.graphql
```

something.graphql

```
mutation createSomething {
  createSomething(data: { key1: "val1", key2: "val2" }) {
    key1
    val1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer.

Turns out you need to nest them all under the `mutation` keyword and then alias them to allow for multiple mutations.

```
mutation {
  something1: createSomething(data: {
    key1: "val1"
  })
  something2: createSomething(data: {
    key2: "val2"
  })
}
```